# How would I make a relative date (like 1 second ago, 2 weeks ago)

Tags: swift, date, datetime, swiftui

I tried

```
Text(Date.now, format:
                     .relative(presentation: .named))
```

and also tried

```
Text(Date.now, style: .relative)
```

But the first one just says "now" even after 24 hours

and the second one is literally just a timer so instead of saying after one minute "1 minute ago" it says "1 minute, 20 seconds" for example. There aren't a lot of resources out there for this particular thing, so help will be appreciated

Comment: It will always say  “now” since the date isn’t stored. Every time the body reloads you get whatever “now” is at that time.

Comment: Oh, ok, how can i make the date stored then

Comment: There are many options. Impossible to tell with the code you have provided. How are you implementing storage in your app? Files, core data, firebase, aws… so many options.

Comment: userDefaults, I don't know if what you said about how "now isn't stored" actually has anything to do with the issue. Because I used Date.now for the second one and that worked

Answer (score 3):

Relative format presents date relatively to "now", it does not track time, we have to provide date explicitly, like

```
Text(Date().addingTimeInterval(-60), format:
         .relative(presentation: .named))
```

rendered as

[image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your first one would stay saying "now", while the second one will update once a second is because:

- The first one simply converts the input data to a string when the `Text` view is first created.
- The second one is a initializer that is specialized for `Date`. It actually creates a publisher behind the scene, that will update the underlying text once a second. However, as you might have found out already, only a few `DateStyle` were supported.

---

One solution is to create your own `Date` wrapper class that conforms to `ObservableObject`:

```swift
class PublishedDate: ObservableObject {
    let date = Date.now

    /// Manually creating a publisher that will emits once a second
    var objectWillChange = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in:.common).autoconnect()
}
```

Now we can store our `PublishedDate` in the view as a `@StateObject`, and it will update relevant sub-views every time `objectWillChange` fires:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var date: PublishedDate = .init()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(date.date.formatted(.relative(presentation: .named)))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this `Text(someDateInPast, format: .relative(presentation: .named, unitsStyle: .abbreviated))`

But you can customise it just playing with presentation and unitsStyle parameters